# Using my site API in the WP plugin instead an iframe

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have created a wp plugin where I added an iframe that displays a map with the markers. In the plugin you can set the marker id and the size of the iframe window. 
The problem is that I got the plugin rejected saying that I can't use an iframe but instead API.

Is there any tutorial on how to use API of my site instead of an iframe? The wp plugin will need to connect to my site and pull some data in order to display proper information on somebody else site. These data are dynamic/changing based on the user input.

this is the iframe I use

```
<iframe src="https://waitington.com/?embed=1&branch_id=14" width="350px" height="600px"></iframe>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6wjpv9c9/)

Answer (score 0):

Hello i hope i can help you out,

Google maps are rendered with the API wich is fully explained in https://developers.google.com/maps/

I strongly suggest you check it out for further info on how to use it, 
regards.

Comment: well, I was thinking of this but how am I going to pull the data from my site to display the data inside the marker?

Comment: it´s in the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/  unless you were refering to something else i am not understanding you will find it there